# Crear objetos a partir de los elementos de un array con el nombre que ya tienen JAVA

Tags: java, primefaces

tengo un array y necesito crear un objeto de tipo Element por cada elemento del array. Me encuentro dentro del bucle con el problema de que no se puede dar a un objeto una variable como nombre por lo que no se como  crearlos ya que se machacaría la variable Element todo el rato.
¿Existe alguna forma en java de hacer esto?

Tengo un array llamado estados y cada estado tiene un atributo nombre. El bucle sería el siguiente:

```
for(int i=0; i<eventos.length; i++) {
    Element start = new Element(eventos[i].getNombre(), "20em", "6em");
    start.addEndPoint(new BlankEndPoint(EndPointAnchor.BOTTOM));
    start.addEndPoint(new BlankEndPoint(EndPointAnchor.LEFT));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo un `ArrayList<String>` con los nombres de las variables como has indicado, haríamos un bucle foreach con el array:

```
for(String nombre : nombreDelArray){
   Element elemento = new Element(nombre, "20em", "6em");
   //Hacer con el elemento lo que quieras hacer
}
```

Lo que hacemos es crear un elemento `Element` por cada uno de la lista, te recomiendo `foreach` para recorrer los listas ya que es mas cómodo.

Comment: Eso es, para listas es mejor foreach, así por cada iteración de la lista va creando un objeto de tipo Element con el nombre que toque en esa iteración.

Answer (score 0):

Dando por hecho que la lista inicial contiene objetos de la clase `Evento` (no indicas la clase concreta):

```
private List<Element> crearElementos(List<Evento> eventos){
    return eventos
        .stream()
        .map(this::nuevoElemento)  //Conversión a Element
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  //Agrupar en una lista
}

private Element nuevoElemento(Evento evento){
    Element start = new Element(evento.getNombre(), "20em", "6em");
    start.addEndPoint(new BlankEndPoint(EndPointAnchor.BOTTOM));
    start.addEndPoint(new BlankEndPoint(EndPointAnchor.LEFT));
    return start;
}
```

Básicamente, se usa el API de `streams` para convertir cada elemento de la clase `Evento` a otro de la clase `Element`,  y se devuelve en una lista.